# how to filter objects to exclude id

Tags: python, django

How can I filter in a query so the result excludes one object in list ?
when
id=1 
model = AutoShow

view:

```
class autoshow_index(ListView):
    context_object_name = "numcar"
    model = AutoShow

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(autoshow_index, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bnrlarg'] = BannerLarge.objects.all()[:1]
        return context
```

template :

```
{% for autoshow in object_list %}    
    <h2><a href="/autoshow_page/{{autoshow.slug}}"> {{ autoshow.title }}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this in your `autoshow_index` class

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return AutoShow.objects.exclude(id=1)
```

Comment: out of curiosity; any particular reason you use id__equals=1 instead of just id=1?

Comment: I do not mean BannerLarge
I mean if id = 1 in AutoShow  I want to exclude it 
Thanks :)

Comment: @jurgenreza - no, just my habit (I froget about `__lte` etc sometimes)

Comment: @creative creative oh, I see. Updated